# How can I make a text area focused after the completion of a jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, show-hide

I have a jQuery plugin in my script, which shows and hides any element in html, which is downloaded from [here](http://papermashup.com/jquery-show-hide-plugin/)

So in my script, it shows and hides a div, as follow:

```
<div class="show" rel="#hild<?php echo $r[id]; ?>">
   <button class="action">
        Respond with a new comment
   </button>
</div>
```

After clicking on this button, the following div is shown:

```
 <div id="hild<?php echo $r[id]; ?>" style="display:none;">
    <form method="post" name="form">
       <textarea rows="5" cols="35" name="texttcons" id="texttcons"></textarea>
    </form>
 </div>
```

So, my problem is when I clicked on that button to show the other div, the textarea needs to be focused after completion of the animation.

Please tell me the solution.

Comment: You want to give focus to a textarea inside a hidden div?

Comment: @wirey he means that when the hidden div is shown when the view button is clicked, textarea should be focused..

Comment: No, the hidden div is to be shown after clicking on that button.

Comment: Could you provide us with the jquery as well?

Comment: if textarea is only one just use it's id to focus. and if you have multiple then how you handle them after POST as they have same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `trigger()`:

```
$('#hild textarea').trigger('focus')
```

instead of that plugin you can use [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method:

> Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

```
$('.show').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('rel')
   $(id).slideToggle('slow', function(){
       $(id).find('textarea').trigger('focus')
   })
})
```

Comment: The problem is here also. I am using it along with php.
so my is named as: <div id="#hild<?php echo $r[id]; ?>">

Comment: @NavedAhmed so you have several div tags, you can try the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

or http://www.mtslo.bplaced.com/jquery/danawoodman-jquery-showhide-7a5c5fd/#example-5

```
$('#hild<?php echo $r[id]; ?>').showhide({
    default_open: false,
    target_obj: '$obj.parent().next()',
    focus_target: '$target.find("input")[0]'
});
```

Why are you using id's? if it is generated by php? why not use a class?

```
$('.ex-2').showhide({
    default_open: false,
    target_obj: '$obj.parent().next()',
    focus_target: '$target.find("input")[0]'
});
```

and html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Toggle the span" class="ex-2">Toggle item 1</a>
        <span><form>label <input /></form></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Toggle the span" class="ex-2">Toggle item 2</a>
        <span><form>label <input /></form></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Toggle the span" class="ex-2">Toggle item 3</a>
        <span><form>label <input /></form></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Update!**

**[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FKSDp/)**

Comment: what is $obj and $target is here ?

Comment: Please note that I used this plugin: https://raw.github.com/danawoodman/jquery-showhide/master/jquery.showhide.min.js in the jsfiddle